# Does calling a virtual protected method from a base class violate the LSP?

Tags: solid, liskov-substitution

Let's say we have this base class:

```
class MyBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string GetDescription()
    {
        var descriptionList = new List<string>() { this.Name };
        descriptionList.AddRange(this.ExtraDescriptions.ToList());
        return string.Join(", ", descriptionList();
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<string> ExtraDescriptions()
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Then add a derived class:

```
class MyDerived : MyBase
{
    protected override IEnumerable<string> ExtraDescriptions()
    {
        return new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
    }
}
```

It seems to me that this violates the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (because we're changing the behavior of the `GetDescription` method), and yet it's also a fundamental feature of object-oriented programming.  The base class *obviously* declares its intention to allow the `ExtraDescriptions` method to be overridden, but this isn't necessarily visible to a consumer of the class.

Ever since I learned about the LSP, this problem has really been gnawing at me.  So:

1. Does this violate LSP?
2. What's the correct alternative to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LSP only requires that a property of a super-class be true of all its derivatives. By "property", in this context, we mean that "it will supply a list of descriptions". The implementation of that is irrelevant.

As far as I can see, there is no violation in your case.

Properties in LSP are much more about the assumptions that can be made by the calling code than they are about the implementation of functionality, or even behaviour.

The canonical example is "a square is a specialised rectangle." But rectangles have height and width properties, which calling code may assume are independent of each other. While a square only really has one dimension, so if I say `rect.X = 3; rect.Y = 2;` and the object is a rectangle, I get a 3x2 rectangle; but with the same calling code on a square, I get a 2x2 rectangle.

Answer (score 6):

It is valid and called template method pattern. It is useful to reduce sequential coupling.

As an alternative, you can use closures, metaprogramming or patterns like policy.

see : http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method for template method pattern and many others.

Comment: The template method pattern requires that the base class be declared abstract (and typically `ExtraDescriptions` would be declared abstract as well).  In this particular case, I've made my base class concrete.

Comment: Well this is just a template method pattern with a default behaviour provided.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock, it is *assumed* but not *required*. The pattern may work perfectly with a concrete base class (which provides default implementations for the virtual methods representing the steps of the algorithm).

Comment: @deadalnix - It sounds to me like the correct alternative is to define the Template Method in an abstract base class, then provide a default implementation of it in one class, and a different implementation in another class.  That way my derived class doesn't inherit from the default implementation, so it doesn't change its base class' behavior.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock > Your solution involve more complexity. You should have a rationnal behind this addition of complexity, other than the base class MUST be abstract. If it does make sense to provide a default implementation, then you just put it in the base class unless you have a reason not to. Making the base class abstract isn't a valide rason. Plus, you can declare your base class abstract even if you have no abstract methods in it in many languages if it doesn't make sense to instanciate it « as this ».

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on what is the expected (published / documented) behaviour / contract of the base class / interface.

If `GetDescription` is meant to return some general, loosely defined description text (comma-separated list of words), it is perfectly fine for different derived classes to add different items to its output via overriding `ExtraDescriptions`. This is the [*Template Method* pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) in action. **[Update]** In other words, LSP is **not** violated in this case.**[/Update]**

If OTOH it is declared to always return the name of the object and nothing else, using a Template Method to open up a possibility of breaking the interface contract wouldn't make the slightest sense. **[Update]** In other words, LSP would be violated in this case.**[/Update]**

Comment: As I commented on @deadalnix's answer, I believe for this to be the Template Method pattern, then `ExtraDescriptions` must be declared abstract, and then that certainly doesn't violate the LSP.  It looks to me like the answer should be to create an abstract base class that implements the Template Method pattern, and then have a `Default` implementation that returns an empty list for `ExtraDescriptions`, and another implementation that returns other lists.

Comment: I can only second @deadalnix's response to your comment. IMO you are overcomplicating your design in search for some high ideal which usually turns out impractical in real life. The overhead doesn't seem big with a single abstract method - but just try to imagine how would your solution scale with ten abstract methods, of which various subclasses require the default behaviour of different ones?

Answer (score 1):

The base class, not the derived class is responsible for LSP. So the creator of the base class should make his class open for substitution. This means that if the base class makes a method virtual, it should be overridable by any function without changing the <s>functionality</s> desirable properties of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, firstly, what you are doing doesn't necessarily violate LSP, if I understand the context correctly. The LSP reads:

> Let q(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then q(y)
>   should be provable for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T.

Now let's translate that to classes:

> Let q(x) be a property of all instances x of class T. Then q(y)
>   should also be a property of all instances y of any class S that is a subclass of T.

Now given the context, that `q` here is basically: *a call to the object's `GetDescription`-method will return a meaningful description of that object*.

In this case you're not violating it. On the contrary, one could argue that you're actually enforcing it, because if you did not override the method accordingly, then the result of `GetDescription` would in fact *not be meaningful* and thus LSP would not hold.
To contrast this, here's a real violation:

```
class MyUndescribable : MyBase
{
    override public string GetDescription()
    {
        throw "can't touch this!";
    }
}
```

I would argue that applying the LSP to non-public members is a bit pointless, because you making any assumptions about non-public members of an instance means violating encapsulation. The only time where this *is* worth considering is, when an instance of `A` calls a protected method of another instance of `A` (which could actually be an instance of a class `B` that has overridden this method).

Secondly, what you are doing would be better achieved through composition, following the DIP. The logic from `ExtraDescriptions` should be passed in, either as a function object, or as an abstract service. This way you could still derive `MyDerived` from `MyBase` (if you really wanted), and pass the logic to the super constructor for example. Thus `MyDerived` would be further decoupled from `MyBase`.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a LSP violation but could drive to it.

Having a virtual default implementation of an interface in a base class means that all subclases that inherits from this base class won't be forced to implement.

So, by mistake, some developer could not implement that would produce an unexpected result during a polymorphic process.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @deadalnix and @PeterTorok's answers, here is, I think, a better implementation that doesn't violate LSP:

```
abstract class AbstractBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string GetDescription()
    {
        var descriptionList = new List<string>() { this.Name };
        descriptionList.AddRange(this.ExtraDescriptions().ToList());
        return string.Join(", ", descriptionList();
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable<string> ExtraDescriptions();
}

class DefaultImplementation : AbstractBase
{
    protected override IEnumerable<string> ExtraDescriptions()
    {
        return new List<string>() { };
    }
}

class OtherImplementation : AbstractBase
{
    protected override IEnumerable<string> ExtraDescriptions()
    {
        return new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
    }
}
```

I also think you could do what @deadalnix said in a comment, which is move the default implementation into the abstract class, like this:

```
abstract class AbstractBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string GetDescription()
    {
        var descriptionList = new List<string>() { this.Name };
        descriptionList.AddRange(this.ExtraDescriptions().ToList());
        return string.Join(", ", descriptionList();
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<string> ExtraDescriptions()
    {
        return new List<string>() { };
    }
}

class DefaultImplementation : AbstractBase
{
}

class OtherImplementation : AbstractBase
{
    protected override IEnumerable<string> ExtraDescriptions()
    {
        return new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
    }
}
```

This allows any overriding class to re-use the default implementation.

Comment: This is what you want if it DOESN'T make sens to instanciate the base class. Neither in the question nor in this answer you give rationnale why you don't whant to instanciate this class. If you are in this case, this solution is valid, but otherwise, this is just adding complexity based on belief. It could be what you whant depending on the case you face. It has nothing to do with LSP.

Comment: Your second solution is almost the same as what we proposed. Making the base class abstract is fine - in fact, making it concrete is usually a bad idea for various reasons, with or without Template Method. However, if you *do* need a default implementation with precisely the same behaviour as the base class, your empty `DefaultImplementation` class is a useless complication.

Comment: @deadalnix, Peter - I agree with what you're saying.  But nobody's answered my question... "does this violate the LSP?"   I think that, first of all, it does, and secondly, nobody really seems to care about it, so why is it such an oft-quoted principle?

Comment: Neither of this is violating LSP as long as the overriden function behave as expected by someone using the base class or as expected in the base class. All are LSP compliant. The choice of one or another depends on other criterias.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock, we attempted to answer your question indeed, sorry if it wasn't clear for you. I updated my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The Liskov Substitution Principle doesn't require that visible behaviour doesn't change - it requires that the behaviour will remain as defined and documented. For a "description" method, the behaviour is likely defined as "returns a string with a suitable human readable description of the object". It's most likely that the exact behaviour *must* change to be compatible with the definition and to not conflict with LSP.

The base class has (hopefully) defined requirements for the protected virtual function. Calling it doesn't violate LSP. Obviously a subclass could provide an implementation that violates LSP, but that's not the base classes fault.